# Responsive Images shrinking / not filling container

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel, shopify

I've got my slider up and running on http://cirrusfitness.com

The problem I'm running into is when I shrink down the browser (to test responsive) the image inside the slider shrinks as well, independent of the carousel container and is creating a large white gap before the panel pager nav.

I have attempted to use background-size: cover but I can't seem to target the correct elements.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: It may be an issue with the jQuery Cycle slider that injects inline styles..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a plug-in for your slider? It seems like the JavaScript automatically generates the styles every time the slide switches, which makes your CSS code over the background useless.

You can try making your background-size !important, but I'm not sure if that would fix it perfectly. Unless you can locate and change the Javascript instead, I don't see any easy way of fixing this.

I have used and would suggest this plug-in instead, which have the images at fixed sizes: http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider

Comment: Im using jQuery Cycle Plugin (with Transition Definitions)
 * Examples and documentation at: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Does anyone have any experience with this plugin? I know malsup is quite popular and Cycle slider is used a lot. I agree that the injection of the javascript is probably the issue, I can provide that file but don't know if that'll help.